# MySQL stored procedure not working properly

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to update a value of table using stored procedure in MySQL but all the other values of the column updated.

My code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ABC(IN id INT,IN amt DOUBLE)
BEGIN
UPDATED emp SET Salary=Salary+amt WHERE ID=id;
END

CALL ABC(101,1000);
```

Comment: Updated is a typo and you should not give parameters the same names as columns and since there is only one statement here you can lose begin and end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change the name of the param

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE ABC(IN myid INT,IN amt DOUBLE)
    BEGIN
    UPDATE emp SET Salary=Salary+amt WHERE ID=myid;
    END
```

SQL code is not case sensitive and in your case the refer to id in `WHERE ID =id`  is not referred  to the param but the column name ..and then all the rows are updated .